# Replace script and css references with contents in HTML via npm run build

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to replace the script and style tags with the full contents of the source files and save it in the ./dist folder.

I have a strange use-case where I can't refer to files outside of the html itself.

I still want to build everything out in a src folder and compile it into a dist folder rather than have one giant file.

Is this possible? Can I set up a script in package.json to do this easily?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style src="./example.css"></style>
    <script src="./example.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="ex">
      Hello world
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
#ex {
  color: red;
}
```

```
function example() {
  console.log('hello world');
}

example();
```

SHOULD BECOME >

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #ex {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function example() {
        console.log('hello world');
      }
      example();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="ex">
      Hello world
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly you need to leverage a JavaScript bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html). Then your npm run script would simply execute the bundler, creating your corresponding JavaScript bundle. Most bundlers can package up other assets such as CSS/Images/Sass/etc...

This would allow you to build out your source code from within your `src` directory in a modular fashion as well as bundle your application's code and assets into the corresponding `dist` directory when you execute your npm run script.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I've used this before to create a bundle.js file instead of a dozen javascript files that import and export to one another, but can it also be used to replace references to that file with the full code?

For instead, instead of <script src="./bundle.js"></script> it would be <script>[Actual code from bundle.js here]</script> ?

Comment: I haven't tried this before, but I suspect this should work just fine as when you include an external JavaScript file such as: `<script src="./bundle.js"></script>` you're just modularizing that code out into another file and then reading its contents in.

Comment: That's actually the problem. We're adding code in a "custom code" area of a form that's generated. Since it doesn't accept external sources, I have to essentially dump all of my code into this box.

Basically, I have to do it wrong in order to get it to work...